# Publish failed using Ant publisher (Eclipse/datanucleus)

Tags: java, eclipse, datanucleus

I am being driven mad the following (apparently hard) error from eclipse.

Publish failed using Ant publisher
  Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/MyServlet/build/classes/com/inver/hotzones/database/BaseNetworkData.class'.

I have seen comments on similar errors where refreshing eclipses view of the project helps but it is not helping me.  Have tried cleaning the project, removing it from the webserver, deleting war files but cant seem to clear it.  I have reset my TMPDIR variable so that it uses a directory on the same filesystem as that appeared to be another possible cause.

The error occurs on classes which have been enhanced by datanuculeus.  I have auto-enhance on the project.  The other references to this problem indicate that it is due to Eclipses view of the project being out of step with the filesystem, and I am guessing that this has something to do with thedata nucleus enhancement.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

I am using Eclipse 3.5.2 with latest datanucleus pluggins.

Stack trace

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/MyServlet/build/classes/com/inver/hotzones/database/BaseNetworkData.class'.
at org.eclipse.jst.server.generic.core.internal.publishers.AbstractModuleAssembler.copyModule(AbstractModuleAssembler.java:172)
at org.eclipse.jst.server.generic.core.internal.publishers.WarModuleAssembler.assemble(WarModuleAssembler.java:31)
at org.eclipse.jst.server.generic.core.internal.publishers.AntPublisher.assembleModule(AntPublisher.java:167)
at org.eclipse.jst.server.generic.core.internal.publishers.AntPublisher.publish(AntPublisher.java:128)
at org.eclipse.jst.server.generic.core.internal.GenericServerBehaviour.publishModule(GenericServerBehaviour.java:82)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publishModule(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:949)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publishModules(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:1039)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:872)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:708)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:2731)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:278)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Comment: Can you find any solution to this problem? I would appreciate if you share how far you have come. Thanks.